# Rails has trouble loading module chain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-engines

I am building a Rails Engine. I defined a controller like this,

```
module A::B::C::D::E
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  # module stuff ... 
end

class ExamplesController < ApplicationController
  include A::B::C::D::E

  # controller stuff ...
end
```

When I start the Rails console, `rails console`, I get the following error,

```
uninitialized constant A::B (NameError)
```

Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the module does not exist at the point you are using it.
Since `A` is not defined, Ruby doesn't know what it is.

Note that the `::` is a scope resolution operator used for *look up*, not *defining* a namespace-like hierarchy.

It would work if you defined `A` first:

```
module A
end
```

Then `B`:

```
module A::B
end
```

Then `C`:

```
module A::B::C
end
```

And so on.

Of course you could also do this:

```
module A
  module B
    module C
      module D
        module E
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```